# What syntactical features of programming languages are problematic for blind programmers?

Tags: accessibility, programming-languages

What are the syntactical features of current languages that prove problematic for screen readers or braille readers? What symbols and constructs are annoying to hear or feel? To the blind programmers out there, if you were to design a programming language which was easier for other blind people to work with, what would it be like?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although it is a very interesting question, it is highly a matter of personal preferences and likings, so I'll answer as if you asked me personally.
*Note*: My working system is Windows, so I'll focus on it. I can write cross-platform apps, of course, but I do that on a Windows machine.

### Indentation, White Spaces

All indentation-related things are more or less annoying, especially if the indentation is made with multiple spaces, not tabs (yes yes, I know the whole "holy war" around it!). Python did teach me to indent code properly even in languages that don't require it, but it still hurts me to write proper Python because of these spaces. Why so? The answer is simple: my screen reader tells me the number of spaces, and the actual nesting level is four times less. Each such operation (20 spaces, aha, dividing by 4, it is fifth nesting level) brings some overhead to my mind and makes me spend my inner "CPU" resources that I could free for debugging or other fancy stuff. It is a wee little thing, you'd say, and you'd be right, but this overhead is on each and single line of my (or another person's!) code I must read or debug! This is quite a lot.
Tabs are much better: 5 tabs, fifth nesting level, nice and well. Braille display here would be also a problem because, as you probably know, a Braille display (despite the name) is a single line of text, usually 14 to 40 characters long. I.e., imagine a tiny monitor with one single line of text that you pan (i.e., scroll), and nothing besides that. If 20 chars are spaces, you stay with only 20 chars left for the code. A bit more, if you read in Grade 2 Braille, but I don't know whether it would be appropriate for coding, I mostly use speech for it, except some cases.
Yet more painful are some code styling standards where you have to align code in the line. For instance, this was the case with tests in [moment.js](https://github.com/moment/moment). There the expected values and messages should match their line position so, for example, the opening quote would be in column 55 on every line (this is beautiful to see, I admit). I couldn't get my pull request accepted for more than a week until I finally understood what Iskren (thank him for his patience with me!), one of the main developers, was trying to tell me. As you can guess, this would be completely obvious for a sighted person.

### Block Endings

A problem adjacent to the previous one: for me personally it is very nifty when I know that a particular code block ends. A right brace (as in C) or the word `end` (as in Ruby) are good, indentation level change (as in Python) is not: still some overhead on getting knowing that the nesting level has abruptly changed.

### IDEs

Sorry to admit it, but there is virtually no *comfortable* [IDE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) for the blind. The closest to such an IDE is [Microsoft Visual Studio](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio), especially the latest version (gods bless [Jenny Lay-Flurrie](https://news.microsoft.com/stories/people/jenny-lay-flurrie.html)!), [Android Studio](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) seems also moving towards accessibility starting with version 2. However, these are not as usable, nifty and comfortable as they are for the sighted users. So, for instance, I use text editors and command-line tools to write, compile and debug my code, as do many blind people around me.

### Ballad of the snake_case, or Another Holy War

Yet another thing to blame Python about: [camelCase](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) is far more comfortable to deal with then snake_case or even [PascalCase](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalCase). Usually screen readers separate words written in camelCase as if they were separated with spaces, so I get no pain readingThisPartOfSentence.
When you write code, you have to turn your punctuation on, otherwise you'll miss something really tiny and "unimportant", such as a quote, a semicolon or a parenthesis. Then, if your punctuation is on, and you read `my_very_cool_descriptive_variable_name`, you hear the following: "my underline very underline cool underline.... underline underline underline!!!" (bad language and swears censored). I tried even to replace underlines with sounds (yes, my screen reader gives such an opportunity), but the sounds can't be so well synchronized because of the higher speech rate I use. And it is quite a nightmare when dealing with methods and properties like `__proto__` (aha, there are two underscores on both sides, not one, not three - well, got it right, I think!), `__repr__` and so on, and so forth. Yes, you might say, I can replace the word "underline" with something really short like "un" (this is also possible), but some overhead is still here, as with white spaces and code nesting.
PascalCase is far better but it implies a bit more concentration, also, since we need to remember putting the first capital letter (oh, I'm too fastidious now, let it be PascalCase, but not those under... oh well, you got it already). This was the reason I gave up with Rust, btw.

### Searching for Functions

As I have already told you, IDEs are not good for us, so text editor is our best friend. and then, you need to search for functions and methods, as well as for classes and code blocks. In certain languages (not Python this time), there are no keyword that would start a function (see, for example, C or Java code). Searching for functions in these conditions becomes quite painful if, for example, you do know that you have a logical error somewhere in the third or fourth function in the file, but you don't exactly remember its name, or you skim through someone's code... well, you know, there are lots of reasons to do that. In this particular context, Python is good, C is not.

### Multiple Repeating and Alike Characters

This is not a problem per se, but a circumstance that complicates debugging, for example, regular expressions or strongly nested operations like `((((a + ((b * c) - d) ** e) / f) + g) - h`. this particular example is really synthetic, but you get what I mean: nested ternary operators (that I love, btw!), conditional blocks, and so on. And regular expressions, again.

### The Ideal Language

The closest to the ideal blind-friendly language as for me is the [D language](http://dlang.org/). The only drawback it has is absence of the word `function` except for anonymous functions. PHP and Javascript are also good, but they have tons of other, blind-unrelated drawbacks, unfortunately.

### Update about Go

In one of his talks Rob Pike, the main developer of the [Go](https://golang.org) language said that no one likes the code style imposed by the Gofmt utility. Probably, no one — except me! I like it, I love it so much, every file in Go is so concise and good to read, I'm really excited about the language because of that. The only slightly annoying thing for a blind coder is when a function has several pairs of parentheses in its definition, like if it is actually a struct method. the `<-` channel operator still gives me moments to think about what I'm doing, sending or receiving, but I believe it's a matter of habit.

### Update about Visual Studio Code

Believe it or not, when I was writing this answer and the first update to it, I wasn't working as a full-time developer — now I am. So many circumstances went favorably for accessibility and me in particular! [Slack](https://slack.com), that virtually every business uses, became accessible, and so became [Microsoft Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) (again, gods bless [Jenny](https://news.microsoft.com/stories/people/jenny-lay-flurrie.html) and her team!). Now I use it as my primary code editor. Yes, it's not an [IDE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) per se, but it's sufficient for my needs. And yes, I had to rework my punctuation reading: now I have shorter and often artificial names for many punctuation signs.
So, calling from end of January 2021, I definitely recommend Visual Studio Code as *the* coding editor for blind people and their colleagues. What is even more amazing is that [LiveShare](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/live-share/), their pair programming service, is also accessible! Yes, it does have some quirks (for now you can't tell what line in the file your colleague is editing if you're blind), but still it's an extremely huge step forward.

Comment: Yes, heard about it but haven't worked with it deeply so far.

Comment: "((((a + ((b * c) - d) ** e) / f) + g) - h" - I can see but find this difficult to read.